# Python : Get Largest number input from User

Tags: python

This is a issue with simple Max number identification which is input by User.

When attempting to get the largest number passed as arguement in function-it works. But when dynamically i get 3 input numbers from User , the Output is not actually Larger number. Please correct.

```
def maxof2nums(x,y):
  if (x>y):
    return x
  return y 

a= input('Enter value for a=')
b= input('Enter value for b=')
c= input('Enter value for c=')

def maxof3nums(a,b,c):
  return maxof2nums(a,maxof2nums(b,c))
print ("Maximum of 3 numbers=",maxof3nums(a,b,c))
```

Comment: pyhton has a `max()` function that takes lists as input. I'd suggest to simply use that.

Comment: Your code is actually working for me? Can you give an example where it prints the wrong number? EDIT: you are comparing lexicographically, convert input to integers with `int(...)` then its working correct.

Comment: Your inputs are `string` values. Cast them to `int()` before you pass to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your code instead of using the built in `max` method, its only a minor oversight that you are comparing strings from your `input` not numbers. Cast them to `int` and it should work correctly.

```
def maxof2nums(x,y):
  if (x>y):
    return x
  return y 

a= int(input('Enter value for a='))
b= int(input('Enter value for b='))
c= int(input('Enter value for c='))

def maxof3nums(a,b,c):
  return maxof2nums(a,maxof2nums(b,c))
print ("Maximum of 3 numbers=",maxof3nums(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

i would have done something like that :

```
nb_list = []
nb_list.append(input('Enter value for a='))
nb_list.append(input('Enter value for b='))
nb_list.append(input('Enter value for c='))

print(max(nb_list))
```